# Spring DisposableBean ошибка при завершении

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

Есть веб приложение(spring). Есть класс который имплементирует интерфейс DisposableBean.

```
public class MyTestService implements DisposableBean {

    private static MyTest myTest;

    @PostConstruct
    public void startMyTest() {
     if (myTest == null) {
            myTest = new MyTest();
        }
        if (!myTest.isRunning()) {
            Thread th1 = new Thread(myTest);
            th1.setDaemon(true);
            th1.start();
        }
    }   

    @Override
    public void destroy() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("DESTROY!!!");
        myTest.setRunning(false);        
    }   
}
```

когда я останавливаю tomcat то в логах ошибка появляется

> DESTROY!!!
>   [localhost-startStop-2] WARN org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter - Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'MyTestService': java.lang.NullPointerException

а затем уже в логах ошибка

> 14-Oct-2015 18:35:21.398 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-6] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
>   org.bytedeco.javacpp.avformat.av_read_frame(Native Method)
>   org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.grabFrame(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:591)
>   org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.grab(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:556)
>   com.company.video.MyTest.run(MyTest.java:68)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

И приложение остается висеть в памяти и работать! В чем моя ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Похоже твой `startMyTest()` просто не вызывается. Поэтому `myTest == null`.

Или представь как пофиксить `@PostConstruct` поведение, или добавь `if (myTest != null)` вокруг `myTest.setRunning(false);`.

Comment: добавлял if (myTest != null) , но это не помогает. 100% myTest != null.
@PostConstruct отрабатывает как надо.

Comment: После того как я останавливаю tomcat приложение продолжает работать и myTest делает свое дело...

Comment: Ты должен убить вот тот `th1.setDaemon(true);`... Это и есьт причина почему твоя Java продолжает жить...

Comment: когда я пишу th1.start(); начинает выполняться метод myTest.run()
Когда этот медот выполнится, то и поток завершится. 
 `public void run() {
                while (running)  { 
// Тут мой код
}`

Comment: не-аю Он же `Daemon`: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/03/what-is-daemon-thread-in-java-and.html

Comment: нет разницы. сделал `th1.setDaemon(false);` результат такой же

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы Spring работал с аннотациями `@PostConstruct` и `@PreDestroy` вы должны определить в конфигурационном файле либо  `org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` либо включить конфигурацию через аннотации с помощтью элемента `context:annotation-config`.